# Class Not Recognised as Return/Parameter Type

Tags: c#

I'm calling a simple method that receives an instance of one of my classes and returns another class instance. For some reason it doesn't recognise them in the method declaration but is fine with them within the method and before the method is called. Can't figure out a reason for this. Here is my code;

```
public ReceiptResponse DownloadReceipt(ReceiptRequest request)
    {
        ReceiptResponse call = null;
        ...
    }
```

`ReceiptResponse` and `ReceiptRequest` both throw errors in the `public` line, but the creation of `call` is fine for some reason. Here is one the classes (both are nearly identical);

```
public class ReceiptRequest
{
    public String ClientID;
    public String PolNum;
    public String RecNum;  
}
```

**MY ERROR**

> Error 16  The type or namespace name 'ReceiptRequest' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**UPDATE**

I definitely have the required using statement because if I hover over `ReceiptResponse` on the creation of `call` line then it displays the using statment in the tooltip.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you checked that you're not missing a closing brace for your class?

Comment: Yup, 2 open braces and 2 close braces in each. Unlikely to have miscounted :P

Comment: @killianmcc What do you mean by "it doesn't recognise them"? Is this design time or run time?

Comment: please post the exact error message.

Comment: @killianmcc You should post more code, i.e. the declaration of the 3 classes (request, response + the one that owns your method) + their namespaces.

Comment: Did you add the using instruction for the ReceiptRequest class?

Comment: Yup definitely have the using, as the other lines that have `ReceiptResponse` on them are showing to be using it.

Comment: Can you tell the Framework you are targeting, can occur when you reference say 4.0 library in a project targeted for *Client Profile*. Also did you try the classic case of restarting VS and then rebuilding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RequestReceipt class is in another project, check the Target framework of both projects. Are the the same? If not, check if the target framework of the project which has the ReceiptRequest class is .NET Framework 4, and the other is .NET Framework 4 Client profile.

A project with Target Framework 4 Client profile cannot reference another project with Target Framework 4 (=full).

Comment: +1. The default framework in Visual Studio 2010 is 4-Client Profile. I hate that because this trips me up every time.

Answer (score 0):

are these classes in a different assembly?
if so you need to reference on project to the other.

are these classes in a different namespace? 
if you need to add a `using` statement at the top of the file, or declare the fully qualified name when declaring the variable.

```
using my.name.space;
...
var receipt = new RequestReceipt();
```

or

```
var receipt = new my.name.space.RequestReceipt();
```

Comment: Yup definitely have the using statement included. I'll update my question.